# Why doesn't DecisionTreeClassifier have prob_classify?

Tags: nltk

As per my knowledge this can be easily done.
Is it on the the roadmap or anybody have a fork that implements this?

Ref: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/91

Answer (score 1):

Because DecisionTree classifiers are not always probabilisty-based classifiers. You can use the probability distributions on a corpus to train a tree, but you can make a DecisionTree yourself, based on chosen decision nodes. 
In this last case prob_classify makes no sense, so that's why I think it is not implemented.